# Tomcat commited virtual memory = more than x2 XmX Setting

Tags: java, tomcat

I'm having difficulties understanding / ignorning current memory commitments (virtual memory) by my jvms.

For better context:

- We're running an closed source java application. We just host / run the application by deploying the delivered .war files. But overall we're are responsible for running the application (this construct, as obscure as it is, is non negotiable ;) )
- OS is RHEL 7, Tomcat v8. Overall we're running several Tomcats with an apache 2.2 in front of them as a loadbalancer
- We experience massive memory swapping. It seems like every time we give the server VM more RAM it immediately gets consumed by the tomcats. Currently we run 7 tomcats with a total 48GB of RAM. The plan is to upgrade to 64GB or even higher but I fear this won't change a thing with tomcats hunger for memory...

[image: Commited Tomcat Memory JConsole]

For security reasons I've blacked out some internal paths/IPs/ports etc.

I do know that the memory consumption of a jvm consits of more than just assigned Heap Space, but in my case Xmx is set to 4096m and commited memory is about 10GB - as seen in the jconsole screenshot but can also be confirmed by a top on the server.
And this just doesn't seem right. I mean - over 2x more than heap space?

I've also read some memory related java stuff, but as stated above - the application is closed source which gives me not that much leeway in debugging / trying stuff out,
And since I am relatively new to tomcat I figured I might as well turn to a more experienced community :)

So here are the main questions, which came up:

- Is there a certain setting I am missing which definatley caps the max
  commited memory size for a tomcat?
- Is the behaviour we're experiencing normal?
- How should I talk with the devs about this problem? We've already done Heap Dumps but they weren't as telling as we hoped. Heap is correctly set and is almost always at around 50% load.

Am I missing something here? 
I know it's hard to tell from a distance, especially if no source code can be provided.
But any help is appreciated :)

Thanks!
Alex

Comment: Do you re-deploy updated war files into an exising Tomcat (without restarting Tomcat itself)?

Comment: Hey Thilo, nope, for re-deploying updated .war files we stop the Tomcats, delete the cache directory (.../tomcat/work/) as well as the already deployed folders in the /webapps directory. We then copy the new .war files, set permissions accordingly and deploy.